# Any rules or borders for Q?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

Are there any rulesets or laws for Q or Q continuum? Anything, that would prevent them from doing... *anything*? Or at least limit them from doing something *really bad*?

In "[True Q](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/True_Q_%28episode%29)" episode Q explains to [Amanda Rogers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Amanda_Rogers) that they can do, have, get, become *anything* they want or appear anywhere they want, with just a snap of fingers. If that is true and if there are absolutely no borders or limits, they can't pass, then how can universe work in general? Or, how did it manage to exist so far?

I mean -- any Q could wipe out Borg, entire human population or even entire universe... with just a snap of fingers. What could prevent Q from doing that?

Comment: What a Q says isn't necessarily true.

Comment: Well, by the same token, anything that one Q can do with a snap of the fingers, another Q can un-do just as easily.

Comment: I think the only thing shown to limit/restrict any Q in the show is rules imposed by other Q.

Comment: Rule one: Q lies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There clearly are rules, because in the TNG episode "[Déjà Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_Q)", Q has been expelled from the Q Continuum for breaking them. However, I don't think it's ever explained exactly what they are.

Comment: Oh, God... what an obvious answer! :> Why didn't I figure this out myself? :> Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is one big, big rule that cannot be broken by those in the Q Continuum: You can never die.

As much is evident in the Voyager episode [Death Wish](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Death_Wish_(episode)), where a singular Q-entity (later known more specifically as "Quinn") has been imprisoned in a comet by the Q for trying to commit suicide.  The entire episode centers around Quinn's struggle to earn his right to die, culminating in him being made human, and then later despite Janeway's urgings commiting suicide as a human.

The episode also suggests other restrictions of the Q, obliquely, through a 'representation' of what it is like to be the Q.  Though nothing definite is given by this representation, the portrayal of a lonely, desolate little shack with bit players on a long stretch of road suggests that there is some limit to their omnipotent existence.

But, more specifically, this shows that Q themselves cannot die - by their own efforts or the efforts of those around them.  And, moreover, they aren't even allowed to try.

Comment: They can't die, but they certainly can be killed (by other Q), like in case of Amanda's parents.

Comment: @trejder Interesting...I forgot that her parents had died...that seems like a contradiction of facts actually.