# Do the Q have rules comparable to Starfleet's Prime Directive?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q, prime-directive

They're obviously not opposed to messing with other races but do they place limits on their interference and/or interactions?

We have witnessed Q (John de Lancie) change or alter many things for his amusement, but he only goes so far and usually puts things back as they were when he gets bored or done with whatever he's up to. I have never seen them 'advance' a civilisation, though Q has saved one or two.

Do they have a rule for this?

Comment: [Any rules or borders for Q?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79096/any-rules-or-borders-for-q)

Comment: @Richard That question though a good one seems to be focused on the limits or rather the lack of limits to Q's power.

Comment: “Q... only goes so far and usually puts things back as they were” — he also got asked to leave the Q continuum after inviting Riker to join. (And subsequently put the Enterprise into a situation where 18 crew members died, and very much stayed that way.) I think he later got stripped of his powers too.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from Memory Alpha.

> In The Eternal Tide, it is revealed that the Q Continuum manifested as a creative force to 'oppose' the destructive potential of the Omega Continuum after it was disrupted and the decay of the universe accelerated. Voyager is later able to slow down the decay to a more tolerable level—shortening the universe's lifespan by a few million years rather than by trillions—as the only way to completely halt and undo the disruption would have erased the Q Continuum from existence as their creative force was no longer 'needed'. Eternal Tide also reveals that there are at least six rules that the Q must obey, with number six being "Don't bring the dead back to life" as the consequences of such an action can be problematic as not even the Q fully know what happens after death.

So they have 6 rules to abide by, but this does not stop Q from messing with Enterprise from time to time. He seems to enjoy judging humans by their past misdeeds.

Quoted from source: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q_Continuum

Apparently, this is a non-canonical work that I am quoting from. But interesting nonetheless.

Comment: This is non-canon, and so the answer should underscore this. Though I do appreciate the thought that even the Q don't fully know what happens after death. If there is God (or god/gods/etc.) in the Star Trek universe, surely  this knowledge can be kept away from Q.